# How can I redirect to my login screen when unauthorized while also returning a 401 status code in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

On our MVC website, we secure our endpoints with the `Authorize` attribute, however I would like to redirect the user to the login screen when this occurs.  My first solution was to redirect on `Application_EndRequest` in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
    protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Response.StatusCode == (int) HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Redirect("/Account/Login");
        }
    }
```

The problem with this is that some of our views are loaded by AJAX, in which case we do not want to show the login screen within dynamically-loaded div (this happens for example when the back button is pressed after logging out).  It would be better if the request still returned the login screen, but with a 401 Unauthorized status code so that we can detect this event. Obviously this will not work with this approach because the redirection relies on a 302 status code.

Instead, I would rather 'insert' the login screen content inside `Application_EndRequest` with a 401 status code.  So, instead of the `Response.Redirect`, I tried this:

```
            ...
            Response.ClearContent();
            Server.TransferRequest("~/Account/Login");
            Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            ...
```

The redirect works nicely, but because this performs a new request, I can't set the status code in this way, and I get a 200.  Still no good for detecting an unauthorized request.

I also tried:

```
            ...
            Response.ClearContent();
            Server.Transfer("~/Account/Login");
            Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            ...
```

But I get an exception "Error executing child request for /Account/Login."

I also tried:

```
            ...
            Response.ClearContent();
            HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("~/Account/Login");
            Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            Response.End();
            ...
```

But this throws an exception "Thread was being aborted".  I'm not sure if the Response.End() is necessary but without it, I just get a standard IIS 401 error.

How can I return the content of my login screen but with a 401 status code?

Comment: Try using custom error handling with 401 set to return a login view.

Answer (score 8):

**Sending a 401 AND a ViewObject or RedirectObject is not how the MVC Framework was designed to work**: -- a few posts have cleverly shown that returning a 401 with a View witn an authorization filter..

I specify the *MVC Framework*, but this is not even the prefered way to use the  *HTTP* Protocol.

- When you redirect in your *MVC* application, you have created a **[RedirectResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.results.redirectresult(v=vs.118).aspx)**
- When your *MVC* application returns with a call to the Controller's `View()` method, a **[ViewResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewresult(v=vs.118).aspx)** is created

Whether a *Redirect* or a *View* eventually reaches the client browser either,

- an `HTTP Return Code` of **200** -- **Success** will be returned

Or

- an `HTTP Return Code` of **302** -- **Redirect** will be returned

The reason for this convention is that, the server is "handling" the redirect. If the user is not authorized, the server will redirect the user to the login page.

Simlarly, in **AJAX** or asynchronous HTTP requests, so long as an **HTML** View is returned, the HTTP request is considered a success. Redirect (302) is not returned for asynchronous requests.

---

**Sending Error Codes to client:**

If you want to return a `401` **unauthorized** to the client, that usually means that you want to the client to "handle" the unauthorized request by navigating to the Login or Error View.

```
$.ajax({
    url: loginURL,
    data: $("#form").serialize(),
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html"
})
.success(function (result, status) {
            /*additional logic*/
})
.error(function (xhr, status) {
    if (xhr.status == 401)
    {
        window.location = unauthorizedUrl; //redirect to unauthorized url
    }
});
```

---

**What if you want to Redirect to Login Page AND Display an Error**

your question makes most sense if you want to redirect to a Login Page AND display an Error

[image: Bad Login Attempt]

Then, the convention is to Add your error message into `Viewbag` or a ModelState Error

such as:

```
        var user = await signInManager.UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);

                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
                return View(model);
```

In your View, to have code that looks for an error:

A `ValidationSummary` would pickup the Model error

```
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

---

This specific example of Bad Login Attempt doesn't exactly speak to your example.

I couldn't find an image for a user redirected because they were not authorized, but, in this case, the logic is similar. Error Msg can be populated with a *QueryString*, *Viewbag*, etc.

Comment: In the answer I have provided below I return a ViewObject and a 401 Status Code.

Comment: @timkly, you're right. I should edit my post and concede that it's clearly possible.

Answer (score 7):

You would ideally want to use a custom `AuthorizeAtrribute` and then hook into the `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` method and from that, return a view to your login page by setting the controller and view to call in the AuthorizationContext.

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "home";
            filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = "login";

            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult ();
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
        }
    }
}
```

note: The trick for this is to make sure you set the following value to true to avoid forms authentication taking over the response once you've set the 401 status.

```
HttpContext.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
```

Answer (score 5):

I tried quite a few different methods all of which had their own sneaky problems. Not sure how your solution is setup but if you need to perform a transfer you can use the following:

## Custom AuthorizeAttribute

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Server.TransferRequest("/Account/Login/?NOT_AUTHORISED=TRUE", false);
    }
}
```

You need to pass a message to the next request, using the QueryString seemed to do the trick. Although you need to remember that anyone can set a QS parameter.

## Set Status Code

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request["NOT_AUTHORISED"] == "TRUE")
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
    }
}
```

## Demo

There's no redirect and the HTTP Status code is set to 401.

[image]